# How do I package a Mac OS application for install?

Tags: macos, installation

I know on windows there are a bunch of installer tools you can use to create an installer, but on Mac OS I've seen two ways to install apps:

1. A DMG file which you download, double-click, then run an application inside - the application typically has you drag an icon to another icon (representing the Applications folder) to install the app
2. Another type of file which launches an apparently standard installer, which sometimes brings up a warning like "This installer may run a program to determine if you can go ahead with the install"

What's the "standard" way of packaging an app for install on Mac OS? Is one of the above the Apple-recommended way?

Thanks.

Comment: Rookie question, but why can't we distribute the .app file on it's own and have the user copy it into the Applications folder, instead of creating a DMG file?

Comment: Because a .app is not a file. It only looks like a "file" to the user, but it is really a "Bundle". A specially structured directory, marked so that user sees it, and drag it as if it was just a file. "Bundles" are very "Mac" thing, and don't travel well via e-mail, or downloads, and especially not on Windows-formatted disks. DMG (Disk Image) files, though, are just "Stream of bytes" on disk - which can easily be transferred.

Comment: @MottiShneor, isn't this what .zip files are for? ;)

Comment: @MKatz .zip files also work (and you see them used sometimes).  A disc image (.dmg) can do additional things though: a click-through license, and a background image for the Finder window showing the mounted image are often used for distributed software images, for instance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Apple is very clearly making the "standard" to be downloading a program from the App Store. This has the benefit of making application installation transparent to the normal user. And, believe it or not, normal people have a lot of trouble with the concept of installing a program. Of course that benefit comes with some costs, but this isn't the place for that debate–there are plenty of other places for that.

Assuming you don't want to or can't go the App Store route, both PKG and DMG are common ways to distribute a program. Use a PKG if you need to install files aside from your application bundle (which should not be a common use case). In all other cases use a DMG that prompts the user to copy the application into the Applications folder. But a lot of your users will not understand that they need to do that (unless your target audience is solely knowledgeable computer users). They will run your application from the disk image. Ideally in this case, your program will detect that it is running from a disk image and offer to copy itself into the Applications folder.

Comment: What Apple does is making things consistent. That is extremely good for end-users.

Comment: Great answer. Some links to intros for the 3 main methods would be appreciated. Start with https://developer.apple.com/osx/distribution/

Comment: could you please elaborate just a little on how can a program tell that it runs from a DMG ? (Which Cocoa/Other API to use?) plus, how can a program copy itself to the Applications folder? This calls for authentication/authorization, isn't it? Is there a sample code for this technique?

Comment: @MottiShneor I know that some applications do that, but I don't know the mechanism, sorry.

Comment: @MottiShneor I think you could check the working directory of the program, it should be either something like /Volumes/NameOfYourDMG/... or /Applications/YourApp.app/...

Comment: @SSteve, could you explain how to go if I need to add a configuration file that can be modified by the users, e.g. to specify a directory where some data lives. To make it clearer, in windows I have an example.exe that reads a data folder that lives in the same directory as example.exe. Right now, I have opted to put the data in the HOME directory where the program tries to read, but it is not very intutive. Any ideas?

Comment: @toto_tico I haven’t worked on Mac apps for years, so I can’t be of much help. You’re probably better off posting this as a new question rather than a comment.

Answer (score 13):

**Packages** works well. If your deployment process must be kept simple, it is great.

The `Quick build` consists of dragging your `.app` onto `Package` and it is done.

For advanced packaging, you can also provide a certificate.

http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html

Answer (score 11):

We're discussing two things:

- first and most importantly, the standard method by which the bits of an executable get laid on the disk in a way that's accessible and properly registered by the system
- second, the mechanism for preparing the .app, as recommended by Apple

An older marketing page on [Apple's site](http://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/softwaredistribution.html) says it's recommended to create packages (so the Installer application can move the bits in place) with the PackageMaker application.
Its usage is described here: mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.25/25.03/2503MacEnterprise-PackagingforSystemAdministrators/index.html.

But as others have mentioned, the elephant in the room is the MacAppStore(MAS for short). Until it's debut, what was standard for large companies was their own custom scripts rolled into an older-style 'bundle' package or using an executable like the VISE installer. Smaller developers usually tried to make their app installable via drag-drop, distributed in zip archives or disk images(for simplicity's sake).
The MAS is different: as of 10.7 it uses a package format (which debuted in 10.5) referred to as a flat package (really a xar archive, explanation [here](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Stuff/Ivanhoe/FLAT.html))
which is transferred over http to a hidden folder, installs directly to Applications(after which the temporary folder it is downloaded to is deleted).  It drops its receipt and a bill or materials file into /private/var/db, and is therefore audit-able by the built-in command line pkgutil tool, described here: mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.25/25.12/2512MacEnterprise-PackagesReceiptsandSnow/index.html

A benefit of using the flat package format is you can pull things over the network more safely and efficiently, but it isn't as easy to work with as bundle packages if you are testing and modifying the package regularly, or iterating to ensure scripts that perform actions or checks work well. Even when flat, putting the pkg in a archive or disk image is recommended for flexibility. More distribution tools expect DMG's than zip's, so there's that as well.

Besides what Apple recommends and what is standard, common practice, there's this article: https://www.afp548.com/2010/06/03/the-commandments-of-packaging-in-os-x/ which discusses the why's and hows (although mainly for system administrators) of packaging for wider distribution. It is greatly recommended to get more of a feel of how and why things go wrong, and what to avoid.

Comment: packagemaker is deprecated for quite some time - instead you should create packages using the pkgbuild command line tool.

Answer (score 7):

Try [Iceberg](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Iceberg.html)!
Another one package creator.

Answer (score 5):

In OS X, many applications are just created as a Relocatable
application bundles that the user just need to copy to the
/Application folder (or any other location). In other cases, when you
need to perform some operations over the machine (such as adding users
or changing permissions) you can use a PKG installer (for example built using [PackageMaker](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/PackageMakerUserGuide/Workflow/Workflow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005371-CH1000-SW1)), which allows
executing some pre and post install scripts and support some basic
installation configuration, like selecting the installation drive.

Sometimes, as with complex server software, you need more flexibility, for example to show custom pages to
the end user requesting information required to install your
application, like the MySQL port and password or proxy information to
download requirements on the fly (or simply to make it look fancier
:)). For this cases there are other installer solutions like our [BitRock
InstallBuilder](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com) (disclaimer, I'm one of the developers).
InstallBuilder also has the advantage of generating multiplatform
installers using the same project with very little customization per
platform.