# Making a software setup for Mac OS

Tags: macos, installation

I have an application developed for windows. I need to make a setup for MAC. Some things that i will need to do in the setup are: (i)Install Mono Framework (ii)Install my app files (iii) Macbundle my application. In short .how do i make a setup for Mac which the user can download and run my software(application.exe) on a mac.  Kindly help.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I package a Mac OS application for install?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014502/how-do-i-package-a-mac-os-application-for-install)

Answer (score 0):

OS X applications are usually distributed as self contained app bundles that don't require an installer.
It seems that Mono provides a package maker that help to create .app bundles from Mono projects: http://www.mono-project.com/MonoMacPackager